# Returning values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, return

I have a (hopefully quite simple) Javascript problem. I've search but found nothing that is really relevant to the problem.

Basically I have a function (addToGlobe) that calls two other functions (codeAddressLat and codeAddressLng) as it runs. The two called functions should both return a float value to the first function, which then uses them. The subfunctions definitely work correctly - I did a print statement to check that the "numfinal" variable in each has a value, and it does.

However, when I add print statements to the calling function (as commented in the code), it returns 'undefined'. Therefore, the problem seems to be when the numfinal value is returned.

Thanks :)

```
function addToGlobe(uname, uid, pmcity) {
    // Get lat & long of city
    var pmlat = codeAddressLat(pmcity);
    var pmlong = codeAddressLng(pmcity);

    log(pmlat);   // PROBLEM! Prints 'undefined'
    log(pmlong);  // PROBLEM! Prints 'undefined'

    // Rest of function removed to keep it simple
}

function codeAddressLat(inputcity) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': inputcity}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var llsplit = new Array();

          bkresult = String(results[0].geometry.location);
          bkresult = bkresult.replace(/[\(\)]/g, "");
          llsplit = bkresult.split(',');

          numfinal = parseFloat(llsplit[0]);
          return numfinal;

      } else {
        log('<b><font color="#C40031">Geocode was not successful:</b> ' + status);
      }
    });
 }

  function codeAddressLng(inputcity) {
        // Basically the same function as above. Removed for simplicity
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codeAddressLat` is not actually returning anything. The anonymous function it passes to `geocoder.geocode` is.

Since geocoder.geocode is running asynchronously, codeAddressLat can't wait around for its answer. So codeAddressLat really can't return anything of value. Instead codeAddressLat needs to become asynchronous too. This is a common pattern in JavaScript.

```
function addToGlobe(uname, uid, pmcity) {
     codeAddressLat(pmcity, function(pmlat) {
        // do something with pmlat
    });

    ...
}

function codeAddressLat(inputcity, callback) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': inputcity}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var llsplit = new Array();

          bkresult = String(results[0].geometry.location);
          bkresult = bkresult.replace(/[\(\)]/g, "");
          llsplit = bkresult.split(',');

          numfinal = parseFloat(llsplit[0]);

          // instead of returning, call the callback with the result
          callback(numfinal);

      } else {
        log('<b><font color="#C40031">Geocode was not successful:</b> ' + status);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a return statement in `codeAddressLat`, you have one inside a callback function defined inside `codeAddressLat`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `codeAddressLat` is not actually returning a value but calling function that you pass a callback function which is returning a value. You need to wait until the geocode operation is complete to retrieve the value of numfinal.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `codeAddressLat` is not returning any value at all hence you are getting undefined as output.

Comment: codeAddressLat is not returning anything at all (which means it is returning undefined by default). The return statement is not in codeAddressLat itself.

Comment: @Matt - yes you are right. Missed to see that enclosed function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The geocode request in the codeAddressLat method call and will not return the value to the caller. Your return is of a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
function codeAddressLat(inputcity) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

    return geocoder.geocode( { 'address': inputcity}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var llsplit = new Array();

          bkresult = String(results[0].geometry.location);
          bkresult = bkresult.replace(/[\(\)]/g, "");
          llsplit = bkresult.split(',');

          numfinal = parseFloat(llsplit[0]);
          return numfinal;

      } else {
        log('<b><font color="#C40031">Geocode was not successful:</b> ' + status);
      }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That `geocoder.geocode` function looks like it is asynchronous. Your `codeAddressLat` and `codeAddressLng` functions returns void before the `geocoder.geocode` function has got data back from the server.

A way to get around it is to nest your calls to `geocoder.geocode` and use variable scoping so that when all the AJAX calls have returned you can call your `addToGlobe` function passing the two parameters you want.

Something like this:

```
codeAddressLatAndLong(pmcity);

function addToGlobe(pmlatlat, pmlatlong) {
    log(pmlat);   // PROBLEM! Prints 'undefined'
    log(pmlong);  // PROBLEM! Prints 'undefined'

    // Rest of function removed to keep it simple
}

function codeAddressLatAndLong(inputcity) {
    // stuff

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': inputcity}, function(results, status) {
      // stuff goes here
      pmlat = parseFloat(llsplit[0]);
      geocoder.geocode({...}, function(results, status) {
         // more stuff
         pmlatlong = something;
         addToGlobe(pmlatlat, pmlatlong);
      });
    });
}
```

Welcome to the world of AJAX.